# How to keep two android support version from project?

Tags: java, android, android-support-library

I am developing an application that use aFileChooser library ([github](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser))
and have some trouble. This is the size of `android-support-v4.jar` file in each project:

- MyProject: 973kb
- appcompat_v7: 973kb (same as above)
- aFileChooser: 607kb (may be an old version)

When I include `appcompat_v7` and `aFileChooser` project into `MyProject` project, there is a config, and I replace a `android-support-v4` in `aFileChooser` with a new one from MyProject (973k). It works

But, when i debug my application, sometime a get an error "Could not find class XXX..." like this:
[image]
So, perhap some class has been deprecated and removed in new version, but the library (aFileChooser) still used them. Then I must:

- Change all deprecated method and class in the library, but It will need
  spend much time to do.
- I reuse an old version (607kb) and rename it to
  `android-support-v4-old.jar`, but it doesn't work. Eclipse still
  check multiple define:

> Multiple dex files define
>   Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;

So, is there any solution that still use the old version. I think replace 2 new `android-support-v4.jar` with an old one is not recommended?

Comment: I highly recommend ditching Eclipse and going to Android Studio. It handles things like imports and build paths much better. It will save you so much time.

Comment: You can't use different versions of the same support library.